# how to Route 70% traffic to ExternalName service and append url?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, istio

I want to route 70% percentage of my traffic coming to service A to an external end point and append the URL.

To achieve this I created an externalName type service which points to external endpoint and then use treafik ingress controller to divide the weight in percentage.

My service definition looks something like this:

```
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: wensleydale
    spec:
      ports:
      - name: http
        targetPort: 80
        port: 80
      selector:
        app: cheese
        task: wensleydale

    ---
    kind: Service
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: test-service
    spec:
      type: ExternalName
      externalName: www.google.com
      ports:
      - name: http
        targetPort: 80
        port: 80
      selector:
        app: cheese
        task: test-service
```

Ingress.yaml:

```
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      annotations:
        traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-weights: |
          test-service: 70%
          wensleydale: 30%
      name: cheese
    spec:
      rules:
      - http:
          paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: test-service
              servicePort: 80
            path: /
          - backend:
              serviceName: wensleydale
              servicePort: 80
            path: /
```

What I want in addition is when traffic goes to `test-service`, I want to append path.
In my `test-service` I want the URL to be something like `www.google.com/something`

I'm open to use other tools to achieve this.

Comment: In your 'www.google.com/something' example, where should the 'something' come from? From the user's request or a rule you set up? I ask because if user request that should happen already with what you've got there. If a rule then I guess you mean you want to rewrite the path.

Comment: @RyanDawson From a rule I set, user just hit host say `www.test.com` and when the request is served by service `test-service` it should serve `www.google.com/something` I tried adding `/something` to externalservice definition but it didn't worked.

Comment: Presumably you want to use 'ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /something' but only for the external service and not the internal one? But that annotation would go at the top level and apply to both. Is that the problem? If so I wonder if you could change the internal service to allow for that path too.

Comment: yes, that's the problem, I can't alter the internal service.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

1. Use Istio Ingress Gateway instead of a traefik gateway. Istio Ingress Gateway is the recommended way for Ingress control in Istio. See https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/
2. In the corresponding Virtual Service, use HTTPRewrite directive https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#HTTPRewrite :

`rewrite:
      uri: /something`

Comment: In the corresponding virtual service can I specify the destination host outside the cluster, say `google.com`?

Comment: Yes, you can if you define the corresponding `ServiceEntry`, see https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/#configuring-the-external-services

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you are hitting a limitation. The traefik ingress docs state this condition on weighting - "The associated service backends must share the same path and host". (https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/#traffic-splitting) So you can't rewrite the path just for one of the weighted targets. The limitation comes from https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25485 so you can see the suggestions there, many of which mention istio. (See also https://github.com/zalando/skipper/issues/324)

A simple solution might be to deploy another proxy into the cluster and use that to rewrite the target to the internal service that you can't change. Then your Ingress would be able to use the same path for both.

Another way would be to look at configuring a proxy using a conf file rather than ingress annotations. Configuration snippets may be enough to achieve this but I am not sure. I suspect you'd be best to deploy an additional proxy and expose it externally and configure it directly (avoiding the Ingress abstraction).